# Cube with rigid body does not fall

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I downloaded the compound collision change example from blender demo files and just added a cube with a rigid body in there.
It does not fall at all.

I tried to delete bake and baked again -> same result

What am I missing here?

Blend file:
[image]

[image: cube rigid body settings]

[image: scene rigid body settings]

result of moonboots answer:

[image]

here my new blend file with moonboots proposed changes:

[image]

Comment: Please [add images of your settings](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/205891/edit) and interface. Information needed to provide an answer should be visible in your question, and not rely on downloading files. Thanks

Comment: i did....want to see more...or something specific?

Comment: @timaroberts: nice, that you "corrected" my text and make it worse in some parts...if you use some "automatic" tools to make uppercases, please check(!) whether it makes it right. In my case your tool capitalizes alle words of my caption which makes abolutely no sense at all. Thank you.

Comment: It is called [title case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_case) as opposed to [sentence case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Sentence_case). But anyway, you are free to rollback if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do 3 things:

- Delete the bake:

[image]

- Apply the scale of the small cube:

[image]

- Choose *Shape > Mesh* instead of *Convex Hull* for your big triple cube object, otherwise it will act like a big box and it will kick out the other objects:

[image]

Comment: i did as you wrote and the good thing: the box is moving, the bad thing: everything is blowing up like an explosion.... see my pic in my updated question

Comment: Delete the bake, select the big structure and choose Mesh instead of Convex Hull and it should work, sometimes it looks like there's a refresh problem but on my computer it works. Maybe try to hide and unhide the big object to see if it refreshes?

Comment: ok, thank you very much! Now it works as expected!

Comment: so was it a problem of refresh or did you forget one of these steps?

Comment: of course my fault. I thought you meant my cube to be as a mesh object because i read too fast and too lazy...when i set the big structure to mesh it did not work either. Then i moved the cube to another collection and deleted bake again and baked ...it worked. And i am glad it did.